# Forms-GUI is *sometimes* blocked

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, user-interface

sometimes the programm keeps calculating 'something' forever(?) and the GUI is blocked. But most of the time ist works. And I have no idea why.

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread (Taskstuff).Start ();

    }

private void  Taskstuff()
     {
         Parallel.ForEach(Pfade, element =>
        {

              DoStuff(element);

        });

    }
private  void DoStuff(string path)
    {
        IEImage Bild = new IEImage(path);
        string name;
        name = Path.GetFileName(path);

        Organizer(Bild);

    }
private void Organizer(IEImage Bild)
    {
        Bild.ConvertToGray();
        Bild.EdgeDetect_Sobel();

        Bitmap VorverarbeitetBitmap = Bild.CreateBitmap();
        //Array für Cluster
        List<Point> points = BildArray(VorverarbeitetBitmap);
        List<Point> Rand = new List<Point>();
        //Clusteraufruf

        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            List<List<Point>> Clusterkopie = DBSCAN.Cluster(points);
            Rand= DBRAND(Clusterkopie[größteclusternummer]);
        }
        //Nur Randaufruf, wenn keine Clusterrechnung notwendig
        else
        {
            Rand=DBRAND(points);
        }

        //Feststellung der Neigung
        bool neigung = Neigung(Rand);

        //Sortieren nach Kreiskoordinaten
        List<Point> sortierung = Sortierung(Rand);

        //Bestimmung des Eckpunktes
         Point ecke = Ecke(sortierung,neigung);

        //Berechnung der Gerade mit den meisten Treffern
        List<Point> Bresenergebnis = Geraden(ecke, neigung, sortierung);

        //Messung Distanz Ecke <-> Kurve in Pixeln
        double distanz = Distanz(Bresenergebnis, ecke, neigung);

        //do more stuff

    }
```

At the moment there is no GUI access in the code. All results are just variables.
And I don't understand why the GUI isn't always blocked or always working. I do not change anything between the attempts. :|
Maybe sometimes the new threads are the same as the old "GUI-thread"?

Comment: You're touching `checkBox1.Checked` from a thread that's not the UI thread. You should pass in any data that your worker needs as a parameter to the thread function and not touch any UI inside the worker. Why don't you use `BackgroundWorker` for this sort of work? It'd make it a lot simpler for you.

Comment: Task would be even easier than BackgroundWorker (and is generally the prefered approach, see also https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html). "new Thread (Taskstuff).Start()" could just be replaced with "Task.Run(TaskStuff)"

Comment: It seem the problem was related to the library I'm using for Sobel/BW-convert. I changed that part to seriel-code.